# How do I exec into a docker container using its image name (as opposed to container ID)?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-exec

I'm using the following version of Docker

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

When I start my containers using "docker-compose up", I can see them all come up with

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
29e94e032fbb   maps_apache     "httpd-foreground"       2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:9090->80/tcp, :::9090->80/tcp       maps_apache_1
13a8f2f037e4   maps_client     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp, :::3001->3000/tcp   web-app
318dff5311a2   maps_web        "bash /my-app/entryp…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   maps_web_1
b4a6914cc67a   postgres:10.5   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:5105->5432/tcp, :::5105->5432/tcp   maps_postgres_1
```

I would like to exec into my docker container using the readable image name, so I tried this

```
$ docker exec -it maps_web sh
Error: No such container: maps_web
```

What's the proper way to exec into docker using the image name (as opposed to the container ID)?

Comment: We cannot exec into a container through the image name. The image is not the container; multiple containers could use the same image. Hence, this might not be a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Did you mean to say "container name"?

Comment: Assign proper container names in the Docker-compose file. Eg. name your container `maps_web`. Problem solved without writing custom shell scripts.

Comment: `docker-compose exec web` will use the Compose service name without needing to manually assign a container name.

Comment: Thanks @David Maze.  To formalize what I think you were describing, I ran "docker-compose exec web sh" and that allowed me to run shell commands from within the container.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to the `docker-compose` suggestion in the comments above.

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf "name=maps_web_1") "sh"
```

`$(docker ps -aqf "name=maps_web_1")` grabs the container ID by searching for the name (per the entries in the far right column when running `docker ps`).

You can use regex patterns to be more specific, like `"name=maps_web.*"`. The caveat here is that this may return multiple container IDs or none at all if you're not careful.

In your case, `$(docker ps -aqf "name=maps_web")` would actually work since there are no other container names prefixed with `maps_web` (it'll use the first one it finds).

UPDATE: you can remove the quotes around the command you're attempting to run if it's causing issues.

Comment: If you know the container name, you can just pass it directly as an argument; `docker exec -it maps_web_1 sh`.  You shouldn't need to manually look up its ID in most cases.

Comment: That's much more elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME=mydockerimagename

docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf "ancestor=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME"| head -n 1) /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are only running a single container, this would work:

`docker exec -it $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}') /bin/sh`

If you are running multiple, you should add -f... to the internal docker ps command.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to identify the container's name, that is on the **'NAMES' column**.

**Run the docker ps command.**

```bash
docker ps
```

Result:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
29e94e032fbb   maps_apache     "httpd-foreground"       2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:9090->80/tcp, :::9090->80/tcp       maps_apache_1
13a8f2f037e4   maps_client     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp, :::3001->3000/tcp   web-app
318dff5311a2   maps_web        "bash /my-app/entryp…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   **maps_web_1**
b4a6914cc67a   postgres:10.5   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:5105->5432/tcp, :::5105->5432/tcp   maps_postgres_1
```

**Then, RUN the docker exec command on the container:**

```bash
docker exec -it maps_web_1 /bin/bash
```

Result:

```bash
root@318dff5311a2:#
```